# How do you keep UISearchBar from resizing/changing height when pressed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

I want my `UISearchBar` to be taller than the default. I initialize the search bar using:

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(0, 0, [[self view] frame].size.width, 60];
[[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:searchBar_];
```

which works fine to initialize the search bar with height 60. However, when the search bar becomes active, it changes back to the default height 44. After that, when search is ended, the search bar height stays as the default height.

Things I've tried:

1. Setting the table header view with a `UIView` of the desired frame that has the search bar as a `subview`. The same thing happens, and it looks weird when search is exited.
2. Setting the frame again in `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`. This wouldn't solve the problem of the search bar resizing when pressed, but I was hoping it would at least make the search bar look the same after search was completed. Instead, it looks weird when search is exited.

Does anyone know how to keep the search bar at the height I want it? I should note that we are doing everything programatically, and that this is for `iPhone`.